# How to avoid repeating code which makes an ellipse move? Currently I have to repeat it for each ellipse

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm trying to add many flying dots to the canvas that connect to each other with a line when the distance between them is between 0 and 300 and have the line's opacity change based on the distance between them. As you can see, I've done all that completely with two dots. However, I'm facing two problems now.

Problem number one - If I wanted to add 15 ellipses, I'd more or less have to copy the code for each new ellipse. I'm fairly certain this is not the way to do it.

The second problem is that I'm hard-coding which dots should connect to each other. I want each dot to connect to each nearby dot, however, I'm not sure how to do that exactly.

```js
var el1 = {
    x: 100,
    y: 100,
    width: 5,
    height: 5
};

var el2 = {
    x: 300,
    y: 300,
    width: 5,
    height: 5
};

var speed = 2;
var opacity = 0;
var xdirection = 1;
var ydirection = 1;

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight - 4);
}

function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight - 4);
}

function draw() {
    background(51, 51, 51);
    fill(55, 90, 80);
    noStroke();
    ellipse(el1.x, el1.y, el1.width, el1.height);
    ellipse(el2.x, el2.y, el2.width, el2.height);
    el1.x = el1.x + speed * xdirection;
    el1.y = el1.y + speed * ydirection; 

    if (el1.x > windowWidth || el1.x < 5) {
        xdirection *= -1;
    }
    if (el1.y > windowHeight || el1.y < 5) {
        ydirection *= -1;
    }
    if (dist(el1.x,el1.y,el2.x,el2.y) < 300) {
        var opacity = map(dist(el1.x,el1.y,el2.x,el2.y),0, 300, 255, 0);
        stroke(55, 90, 80, opacity);
        line(el1.x,el1.y,el2.x,el2.y);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.2/p5.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you make a 'class' for the dots, you don't have to repeat the code. Or you could restructure the functions so they operate on an array of dot definitions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define your ellipse as an object, create them as many as you want (15), put into array and start drawing, constantly detecting the distance between all of them.

Object himself:

```
var noOfEllipses = 15;

var opacity = 0;
var arrOfEllipses = [];

class Ellips {
    constructor(x, y, w, h, s=2, dx=1, dy=1){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.w = w;
        this.h = h;
        this.s = s;
        this.dx = dx;
        this.dy = dy;
    };
}
```

Next, initial drawing. I gave dots random dimensions and locations, you can add any individual property (speed/direction/color/etc).

```
function randInt(min, max) {
  min = Math.ceil(min);
  max = Math.floor(max);
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

function setup() {
    createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight - 4);
    for(i=0; i<noOfEllipses;i++){
        var el = new Ellips(
            randInt(3, windowWidth),    //x
            randInt(3, windowHeight),   //y
            randInt(3, 8),              //width
            randInt(3, 8),              //height
            randInt(10, 50)/10          //speed
            );
        arrOfEllipses.push(el);         //put them into array
    }
}

function windowResized() {
    resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight - 4);
}
```

Animation. Iterate through array of dots, location/speed/etc. are inner properties. Second for{} is needed to calculate distance and draw lines.

```
function draw() {
    background(51, 51, 51);
    fill(200, 200, 80);
    noStroke();

    for(var i=0; i<arrOfEllipses.length; i++){
        el = arrOfEllipses[i];
        el.x = el.x + el.s * el.dx;
        el.y = el.y + el.s * el.dy;

        if (el.x > windowWidth || el.x < 5) {
            el.dx *= -1;
        }
        if (el.y > windowHeight || el.y < 5) {
            el.dy *= -1;
        }
        for(var j=i+1; j<arrOfEllipses.length; j++){
            el2 = arrOfEllipses[j];
            if (dist(el.x,el.y,el2.x,el2.y) < 300) {
                var opacity = map(dist(el.x,el.y,el2.x,el2.y),0, 300, 255, 0);
                stroke(200, 200, 80, opacity);
                line(el.x,el.y,el2.x,el2.y);
            }
        }
        ellipse(el.x, el.y, el.w, el.h);
    }
}
```